# Issues updating dictionary at run-time across multiprocesses

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to configure some keybindings with pygame that can be dynamically changed/updated at runtime. You can see my first prototype attempt below. I'm getting a confusing error message that I'm stuck on. It's complaining during initialization that multiprocessing/connection.py can't access 'Pitch' in test.py.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-2017.2.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1599, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-2017.2.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1026, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-2017.2.3/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/jesse/code/pygame_controller/test.py", line 56, in <module>
    test_rpyc()
  File "/home/jesse/code/pygame_controller/test.py", line 42, in test_rpyc
    i = InputProcess(mapping)
  File "/home/jesse/code/pygame_controller/input_rpc.py", line 111, in __init__
    i = Input(mapping)
  File "/home/jesse/code/pygame_controller/input_rpc.py", line 58, in __init__
    set_mapping(mapping)
  File "/home/jesse/code/pygame_controller/input_rpc.py", line 52, in set_mapping
    _mapping.update(mapping)
  File "<string>", line 2, in update
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 732, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
multiprocessing.managers.RemoteError: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 228, in serve_client
    request = recv()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Pitch' on <module '__main__' from '/home/jesse/code/pygame_controller/test.py'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I debug, inside connection.py, I can look through the whole mapping dictionary. It appears connection.py has the dict object which is why I'm confused why it's throwing an error in the end. Does the multiprocess module not have access to the namedtuple 'Pitch'? I can change the 'Pitch' namedtuples to integers and then this code works fine. Is there a better way to update the mapping, possibly with rpyc? Rpyc is what I was going to prototype next if I can't make progress here.

**test.py**

```
from collections import namedtuple
from input import event_queue, InputProcess

Pitch = namedtuple('Pitch', 'value')

mapping = {
    'keyboard': {
        'w': {  # key
            'key_down': Pitch(-1.0),  # event
            'key_up': Pitch(0.0),  # event
        },
    },
}


def test():
    i = InputProcess(mapping)
    i.start()

    while True:
        event = event_queue.get()
        print(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

**input.py**

```
import pygame
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process

_manager = Manager()
_mapping = _manager.dict()

event_queue = _manager.Queue()


def initialize(joystick=True):
    """Initialize pygame & joystick"""
    ...


def set_mapping(mapping):
    """Change the current keyboard/joystick mappings"""
    global _mapping

    for k, _ in _mapping.items():
        _mapping.pop(k)

    _mapping.update(mapping)


class Input(object):
    def __init__(self, mapping=None):
        if mapping is not None:
            set_mapping(mapping)

    @staticmethod
    def run():    
        while True:
            event = pygame.event.wait()

            # handle event


class InputProcess(object):
    def __init__(self, mapping=None):
        initialize()
        i = Input(mapping)

        self.process = Process(target=i.run)

    def start(self):
        self.process.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.process.terminate()
        self.process.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the key.

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Pitch' on <module '__main__' from '/home/jesse/code/pygame_controller/test.py'>
```

`test.py` is running as `__main__`. If you create a new file which imports what you need and run from there, then it will be able to access `Pitch` in `test.py`.

Example:

example.py

```
from .test import test

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```